# AngularJs Dynamic currency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am working on a requirement to change the currency displayed on a record based on currency.

The symbol of the currency is not a problem, as I can change it using

```
{{value | currency:"$"}}
```

But the problem is with thousand and decimal separator.

```
For euros: 1,00.00 €
For dollars: 1.00,00 $
```

I tried some solutions. But none of them helped, which makes my question repetitive.

I tried to load the script using following code with localization changes. But it did not help.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "../js/switzerland.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s)
```

The script element reflects in the header. But the currency does not change. Any solution?

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXdAXg thousands and decimal separator seems to be working

Comment: what is the input and what is expected value to display??

Comment: @NagaSaiA Expected: for Euro(€), thousand separator is dot(".").....
for dollar: thousand separator is: comma(",")....and similarly for fraction separator it should be reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below

HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>{{curr | currency:"$"}}</div>
  <div>{{curr.toLocaleString("es-ES",{minimumFractionDigits: 2})}}€</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.curr = 1230.00;

});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXdAXg